# SQL merging two cells into one (much like & in excel)

Tags: sql

Could you please help me how to merge two cells into one?

For example, table1 has column A and column B

[image: Table1]

And I want to extract data as below

[image]

Please help, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT CONCAT(A, B) AS combined FROM table1`